# Javascript class instance not found

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, monocle

I am using MonocleMVC. I am creating a new class instance with the following code :

```
__Controller.Lists = new ListCtrl('article#lists')
```

(`__` internally refers to `Monocle`)

The code inside `ListCtrl` works, but I can't access the variable `__Controller.Lists`. It says it is undefined.

However, `__Controler.Sessions` is defined in the following code :

```
__Controller.Sessions = new SessionCtrl('section#splash')
```

**UPDATE**

It seems this code prevents the class from being defined :

```
class ListCtrl extends Monocle.Controller

# THIS CONSTRUCTOR
  constructor: ->
    super
    __Model.List.bind "create", @bindCreate
    __Model.List.bind "change", @bindChange
    __Model.List.bind "error", @bindError
    __Model.List.bind "destroy", @bindDestroy
    @bindChange()
```

**UPDATE 2**

Turnet out `@bindChange()` was the cause. Any idea why?

Comment: There may be an error somewhere else in your code. Are you sure everything compiled correctly? Are there no errors in the console?

Comment: Thank you. I found the source of the problem. I update my answer